# Perl - ignoring certain things during a diff, but adding them back afterwards

Tags: regex, perl, diff

I have two files that I want to diff. The first file looks like this:

```
<error line="3" message="message 1"...
<error line="4" message="message 2"...
```

The second looks like this:

```
<error line="4" message="message 1"...
<error line="5" message="message 2"...
<error line="5" message="message 3"...
```

I want to ignore the line numbers during the diff so I used some regex to set all the line numbers to be the same. So now file #1 looks like this:

```
<error line="." message="message 1"...
<error line="." message="message 2"...
```

And file #2 looks like this:

```
<error line="." message="message 1"...
<error line="." message="message 2"...
<error line="." message="message 3"...
```

However, once the diff returns its output, I will need to get the line number back for every element of the diff output (i.e. in this case I will want the line number back for `<error line="." message="message 3"...` ). Does anybody know how this can be done? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
The actual files used are Checkstyle outputs written to a file.

File 1:

```
    <checkstyle version="5.3">
    <file name="d:\var\temp\cstemp\.\File1.java">
    <error line="1" severity="warning" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocTypeCheck"/>
    <error line="1" severity="warning" message="Missing package declaration." 
    </file>
    </checkstyle>
```

File 2:

```
    <checkstyle version="5.3">
    <file name="d:\var\temp\cstemp\.\File1.java">
    <error line="2" severity="warning" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocTypeCheck"/>
    <error line="2" severity="warning" message="Missing package declaration." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.PackageDeclarationCheck"/>
    <error line="10" column="9" severity="warning" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck"/>
    <error line="10" column="35" severity="info" message="&apos;{&apos; is not preceded with whitespace." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck"/>
    <error line="14" column="9" severity="warning" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck"/>
    <error line="14" column="29" severity="info" message="&apos;{&apos; is not preceded with whitespace." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck"/>
    <error line="15" column="21" severity="info" message="Variable &apos;a&apos; should be declared final." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.FinalLocalVariableCheck"/>
    <error line="15" column="25" severity="info" message="&apos;5&apos; is a magic number." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MagicNumberCheck"/>
    </file>
    </checkstyle>
```

I only want to know about new Checkstyle errors which is why I removed the line numbers and then performed the diff. But once I know which errors have been added, I need the line number associated with that error.

Comment: This looks like XML. If it is, then it's quite easy if you use a parser. But will be easier to answer if you can give us some valid/complete XML and an expected output.

Comment: What's the desired result here? Because you've lost data by deleting line numbers. Putting them back is doable, but you'd be _far_ better off _not_ doing that and instead comparing just based on message.

Comment: Are the messages actually unique in each of the files?

Comment: Don't know how they can be, because if they were, `diff` would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Looking at it - I think we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it _looks_ like we're trying to compare 'message' fields in two files.

Comment: @Sobrique I want to know if any new errors have been added in file #2. If somebody adds a few blank lines to the beginning of file #1, then they would all be treated as new errors in the diff output due to the differences in the line numbers. This is the reason I've removed the line numbers.

Comment: Removing the numbers may not be the right answer, as you may have a structured data format there - if it is in fact, XML - you can parse it as XML and compare just the "message" attribute, for example. Being able to re-add the line numbers presumes that there's a degree of uniqueness/referring back to the original file.

Comment: The actual files are Checkstyle outputs. I'll stick an example in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like XML, so I'm going to proceed on the assumption that it is actually XML. If that's not a valid assumption, then ... this won't work. But then whoever wrote those log files is a bad person for making fake XML.

So as I understand it - you want to extract unique 'message' attributes from two files, and pick out the ones that are 'missing'?

Something like this will do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $first = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('samplec.xml');
my $second = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('sampled.xml'); 

foreach my $error ( $second -> get_xpath('//error') ) { 
   my $message = $error -> att('message'); 
   $error -> print unless $first -> get_xpath("//error[\@message=\'$message\']");
}
```

This compares *just* on message content - which your example suggests is unique (and searches the other structure for a matching message, anywhere in it). Which may not be exactly what you're after, but a similar technique should be able to do what you want.

Following update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $first = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('samplec.xml');
my $second = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ('sampled.xml'); 

my @first_errors = $first -> get_xpath('//error');
my @second_errors = $second -> get_xpath('//error'); 

my $first_err = shift ( @first_errors ); 
my $second_err = shift ( @second_errors );

while ( @first_errors or @second_errors ) { 
   if ( defined $first_err and $first_err -> att('source') eq $second_err -> att('source') ) { 
       ## match
   }
   else {
       #doesn't match, so we print
       $second_err -> print;
       print "\n";

   }     
   $first_err = shift ( @first_errors ); 
   $second_err = shift ( @second_errors ); 
}
```

We parse the XML in the first and second files, and iterate each printing as we go. Note - this isn't strictly a `diff` as it assumes that the errors in the first file are a subset of the errors in the second. (But not the other way around). But it should serve to print the new error lines based solely on 'source'

With your sample data it outputs:

```
<error column="9" line="10" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." severity="warning" source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck"/>
<error column="35" line="10" message="'{' is not preceded with whitespace." severity="info" source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck"/>
<error column="9" line="14" message="Missing a Javadoc comment." severity="warning" source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck"/>
<error column="29" line="14" message="'{' is not preceded with whitespace." severity="info" source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck"/>
<error column="21" line="15" message="Variable 'a' should be declared final." severity="info" source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.FinalLocalVariableCheck"/>
```

Comment: Sorry my example was unclear. I've added the actual files to the question. I want to find out about newly added errors in File 2. However, if somebody adds a newline to the beginning of File 1, everything will be treated as new errors even though there won't actually be any new errors,

Comment: OK. I will update. What's your comparison criteria? Just order within the XML?

Comment: Yep that's right. Once I remove the line numbers I'm assuming if the errors are there in the same order then they are existing errors (so the diff will ignore these). The output from the diff would show me any newly introduced errors but once I know which errors are new, I want to get the line numbers back. Thanks for helping so far